# Eagerly loading multiple levels error: "The Include property lambda expression is invalid"

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core 2.1 library that is leveraging Entity Framework Core v.2.2.4 with a MySQL database. I am using the code first model. I have service classes that depend on the `SoarDataContext` class seen below.

When I try to eagerly-load multiple-level nested entities by using the `.Include()` method in [the way suggested in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#eagerly-loading-multiple-levels), I get the following error:

> "Error fetching productions: The Include property lambda expression 'p => {from Participant m in p.Participants select [m].EmergencyContacts}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393."

Here is the service method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Production>> GetProductions()
{
    var productions = _context.Productions
        .Include(p => p.AuditionTimes)
        .Include(p => p.Participants.Select(m => m.EmergencyContacts))
        .ToList();

    return await Task.FromResult(productions);
}
```

My intent in the above code is to get all `Productions` back with all `AuditionTimes` "pre-fetched" and all `Participants` pre-fetched with all of *their* `EmergencyContacts` pre-fetched as well. Because this is the suggestion from the docs and it's blowing up the way it is seems contradictory.

FWIW, here is the class definition for my `DataContext` class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Models;

namespace DataAccess
{
    public class SoarDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public SoarDataContext(DbContextOptions<SoarDataContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Participant> Participants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ParticipantType> ParticipantTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Production> Productions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmergencyContact> EmergencyContacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AuditionTime> AuditionTimes { get; set; }

        //protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        //{

        //}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasIndex(u => u.Username)
                .IsUnique();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Participant>()
                .HasOne(p => p.ParticipantType);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Participant>()
                .HasIndex(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.ProductionId })
                .IsUnique();

            modelBuilder.Entity<ParticipantType>()
                .HasIndex(pt => pt.Type)
                .IsUnique();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Production>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Participants);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Production>()
                .HasMany(p => p.AuditionTimes);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Production>()
                .HasIndex(p => new { p.Name, p.SeasonName, p.SeasonYear, p.AgeRange })
                .IsUnique();

            modelBuilder.Entity<EmergencyContact>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Participant);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AuditionTime>()
                .HasIndex(a => new { a.ProductionId, a.StartTime, a.EndTime })
                .IsUnique();

            modelBuilder.Entity<AuditionTime>()
                .HasOne(a => a.Production);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**:
When trying the answers being suggested, I had a hard time with Visual Studio 2019's IntelliSense. For anyone running into IntelliSense suggesting you're syntax is invalid, try to compile anyways. I found it particularly confusing that the suggested answers wouldn't even compile, but it turns out IntelliSense was just giving me inaccurate errors. As mentioned [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels):

> Current versions of Visual Studio offer incorrect code completion options and can cause correct expressions to be flagged with syntax errors when using the ThenInclude method after a collection navigation property. This is a symptom of an IntelliSense bug tracked at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8237. It is safe to ignore these spurious syntax errors as long as the code is correct and can be compiled successfully.

Comment: You can drill down through relationships to include multiple levels of related data using the ThenInclude method. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels

Answer (score 2):

The initial documentation you linked to is for Entity Framework 6 while the error message links to Entity Framework Core.

Reference [Loading Related Data: Including multiple levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels)

> You can drill down through relationships to include multiple levels of related data using the `ThenInclude` method.

```
var productions = _context.Productions
    .Include(p => p.AuditionTimes)
    .Include(p => p.Participants)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.EmergencyContacts)
    .ToList();
```

Service method could be refactored to

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Production>> GetProductions() {
    var productions = await _context.Productions
        .Include(p => p.AuditionTimes)
        .Include(p => p.Participants)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.EmergencyContacts)
        .ToListAsync();

    return productions;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me, although IntelliSense was giving me feedback that my syntax was not correct. As found in the _correct_ documentation you shared (thank you!), this is a known bug being addressed in newer versions of VS. Thanks again

Comment: @SteveBoniface Glad to help. If this resolves the original issue. Mark it as the answer.